# Google Charts v-axis takes data value, and it is not in order

Tags: charts, google-visualization

There is something really wrong with my chart.. Here is the code used to draw the chart;

```
function drawOne() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../../Graphs/getGraphOne',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { artist: $('#js-id').val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            var xrj = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

            var options = {
                hAxis: {
                },
                vAxis: {
                },
                legend: { position: "none" },
                colors: ['#0aa289']

            };

            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));

            chart.draw(xrj,google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options) );
        }
    });
}
```

With this I get this result;
[Example Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMWIu.png)

So as you can see from the picture, the v-axis displays the value of the column, but these values displayed on the v-axis is not in any order.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks as though the v-axis values are being passed as strings instead of numbers, resulting in a _Discrete_ axis vs. a _Continuous_ axis -- [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35368072/5090771) should help explain...